# Include references to appendix without including appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, input

I'm preparing a latex document using the `input` command. There's a separate file for the appendix called `appendix.tex`. I wish to add references to theorems in the appendix in the main paper, but I don't want to have the appendix in the final compiled pdf. Is there a way to achieve this (without manually cropping pages from the final pdf)?

To elaborate further: Right now, if I don't include `\input{appendix}`, I get a lot of `??` (broken references) in my pdf. I wish to replace the `??` with the right theorem numbers without including the appendix.

Comment: Well, is it very useful to have references to theorems etc. that can't be looked after then, because you omitted the appendix?

Comment: Presumably a journal editor has requested that the body of the paper be submitted separately from an online appendix.

Comment: I agree with @pnj, this seems to be increasingly common.

Answer (score 4):

First, I agree with Christian Hupfer. I would be annoyed reading such a document. Second, providing the appendix as an additional PDF may be a good idea, but it's a bit more complicated then goofynos answer suggests, if the page numbers should be continous across both files. And if there are cross references from the appendix to the main part, it get's even more complicated.

But if you really want a PDF file with cross references going nowhere, there are two ways to achieve this. For both you need to compile your PDF with the appendix attached first to get all references right. Then, after some changes to the main file, you need to compile the file one more time to get rid of the appendix.

Solution 1, with `\include`:

Here you need to add `\includeonly{<files>}` to the preamble for the last run. `<files>` is a comma seperated list of all included files with the exception of those for the appendix.

Note that `\include` always starts a new page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% uncomment for last run
% comma seperated list of all files except those for appendix
%\includeonly{main}

\begin{document}
\include{main}

\appendix
\include{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Solution 2, with `\input`:

Here you need to comment out the files for the appendix and add `\nofiles` to the preamble. The latter prevents LaTeX from writing auxiliary files, so the informations about the `\label`s there are not overwritten.

Note: `\input` does not start a new page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% uncomment for last run
%\nofiles

\begin{document}
\input{main}

\appendix
% comment out for last run
\input{appendix}

\end{document}
```

For completeness, `main.tex`:

```
\section{Main text}
\lipsum[1]

Reference to appendix: \ref{lia}

\lipsum[2]
```

and `appendix.tex`:

```
\section{Stuff}
\label{lia}
\lipsum[3]
```

Comment: This solution probably will not be accepted if the journal requires "The package should contain everything necessary to build the camera-ready PDF, and should compile once unarchived, without having to update any file routes nor hardcoded information in the sources."? Is there a possibility where one only has to compile it once?

Answer (score 1):

Please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) next time.

---

You can do it with a little trick:

Run your `appendix.tex` via `\input{appendix.tex}` in an external document.
Then use the `xr-hyper` package to include the external document with `\externaldocument{extfile}`. Make sure you run the `extfile.tex` on its own minimum once.

You will have a three file MWE:

### Main document

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\externaldocument{extfile} 

\begin{document}
\autoref{sec:external}

\autoref{sec:local}

\section{Local section}\label{sec:local}
% \input{appendix}
\end{document}
```

### External Document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\input{appendix.tex}
\end{document}
```

### Appendix

```
\section{Appendix}
\label{sec:external}
```

Comment: This solution probably will not be accepted if the journal requires "The package should contain everything necessary to build the camera-ready PDF, and should compile once unarchived, without having to update any file routes nor hardcoded information in the sources."? Is there a possibility where one only has to compile it once?